# Desktop Notification in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, notifications, push-notification

I'm using below javascript for desktop notification in asp.net. On button click this event is working fine with permission but getting error while implementing from code behind.

and this code added on my webpage...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function notifyMe() {
            if (!("Notification" in window)) { alert("This browser does not support desktop notification"); }
            else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                var options = {
                    body: "This is the body of the notification",
                    icon: "stupidcodes.com.png",
                    dir: "ltr"
                };                   

                var notification = new Notification("Hi there", options);

                notification.onclick = function () {
                    window.open("http://www.stupidcodes.com/");
                };
            }
            else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
                Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                    if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
                        Notification.permission = permission;
                    }
                    if (permission === 'granted') {
                        var options = {
                            body: 'This is the body of the notification',
                            icon: 'stupidcodes.com.png',
                            dir: 'ltr'
                        };
                        var notification = new Notification('Hi there', options);
                        notification.onclick = function () {
                            window.open('http://www.stupidcodes.com/');
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Is there any method to add notification like this in asp.net

you can check this code working [here](http://www.visionsecurity.in/notification.html)

Comment: did you get this working ?

Comment: No still not @SachinTrivedi

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [my blog post](https://dotnetsachin.wordpress.com/2015/10/09/send-desktop-notifications-using-browser/). I have created a sample that will fire notification when document is loaded. You can leverage the code as per your requirements.

Comment: Let see will check for sure can you reply my current question @Sachin

Comment: Please specify what is the error that you are getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255591/get-filter-the-date-rand-in-sql-server/33255764#33255764 check this