# Get filter the date rand in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data table with `MobileNo` and `RequestTime`, there are two rows with mobile no and date. I want to get all record with current date

```
SELECT * 
FROM Requester 
WHERE (Convert(datetime, RequestTime, 103)) = GETDATE()
```

I have the datetime as a string, so I need to convert it to `DateTime` in SQL but still the result is null

Have a look the code and result in SQL Server

[image]

Comment: If it's a date - ***why*** isn't it **stored** as a `DATE` or `DATETIME` in the first place? Fix that problem first - then deal with the others....

Comment: Data store as string in client machine I cant change all things. you just reply to get the result @marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '21/10/2015', 103)` return: `2015-10-20 00:00:000.000`

`SELECT GETDATE()` return: `2015-10-20 16:42:01.154` -- get current time

You can try your code like this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, RequestTime, 103) = CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime style you chose for the conversion is correct however this is not working because `GetDate()` gives you also the current **time** while your stored dates doesn't. Hence the equal cannot be true.

You need to truncate the time of your comparison date to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT REQUESTERMOBILE,REQUESTTIME
FROM REQUESTER
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(DATETIME,REQUESTTIME),103) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103)
```